# PHP/Javascript content in mail body

Tags: php, email

I have a simple example where I set the 'content-type' to 'text/html' and the received email looks like this:

```
Subject: Test msg
Content-Type: text/html; charset="Windows-1252"
<?php echo '<h1>Test</h1>'; ?>
```

But the shown message in the email window is this:

```
Test'; ?>
```

Do I have to change the content-type to something else or is it not even possible to do this?
Would it be possible with javascript?

Comment: You cannot execute PHP or Javascript on the emailclient... So it displays the message exactly the way you send it (after some html-mark-up parsing)

Comment: If you're sending *actual PHP code* as part of the mail body, that won't work.  Nobody's mail client is going to execute code.  Emails are not applications, they should be kept very simple.

Comment: Where do you have your email body stored and how do you access it to include it in your email?

Comment: @nl-x what do u mean with stored?

Comment: @wasp256 well, how do you generate the above? Is it saved in a file? Is it a `.php` file? Is it `include`d or `fread()`? Or is it from the database? Is it `eval()`'ed?

Comment: I send the mail via c++ (curl) and the above is simply the original message header from gmail; the `Test'; ?>` is the message I see in the email body